# If a die is rolled $10$ times, what is the probability that the number of even results differs from the number of odd results by at most $2$?

Tags: probability, dice

Here is the problem:

> A fair die is thrown independently $10$ times. What is the probability that difference between the amount of obtained even results and amount of odd results is lower than or equal to $2$?

I understand that problem on this way:

If the difference between the amount of obtained even results and the amount of odd results has to be lower than or equal to $2$ and we roll the die $10$ times we are looking for situation where $5$ results of rolls are even and $5$ are odd (difference is $0$, so lower than $2$) or we have $4$ even results and $6$ odd results (difference $2$) or we have $6$ even results and $4$ odd results (also difference $2$).

If we roll the symmetrical die, the chance for odd result and even result is $1/2$.

When we roll the die $10$ times we have $1/2^{10}$ possibilities which means that the chance for result we want is $1/1024$.

This is where I am stuck. Do you have any ideas how to solve it or do you see some mistakes in what I have written?

I forgot to mention that is it closed question and possible answers are $A=0,6563; B=0,2461; C=0,4512; D=0,1719$.

Comment: If we think of each role as an object and even / odd as bins, how many ways are there to sort 10 objects such that 6 or more are in the appropriate bin?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Numbers of even results can be 0,1,2...10. Extreme values are very rare, consider it is 3% for total of these 4 extreme values. Other values have a sum of 96%, and they are regularly disposed. So something like P(2)=4%, P(3)=7%, P(3)=11% , P(4)=16%, P(5)=25%, and symmetric values. Total of P(4)+P(5)+P(6) is greater than 50%. So it is 65%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simplify the outcomes to even, odd, we get  a binomial $(10,\frac12)$, yielding

$$\operatorname{Pr} = \dfrac{2\binom{10}{4}+\binom{10} 5}{2^{10}} = \frac{21}{32}  \approx 0.6563$$

**Added**

The first term in the numerator takes care of both $6$ even and $4$ even, and the second term is for $5$ each of even and odd.

Comment: I think we can't do that like that. This is closed question and possible  answers are: A =0,6563  B = 0,2461  C = 0,4512 D=0,1719. When I put your equation into caluculator it showed 0,0869. Do you have any other idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I was very hurried,  have edited.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you tell me what method have you used? I would like to learn it to be able to do similar problems on my own.

Comment: @krzst: You were on the right track, you had already pinpointed the three cases, 6-4, 4-6, 5-5. Since we are only converned with odd-even, and results are symmetrical, i.e. 6-4 will have the same probability as 4-6 with even odds, I have just used the binomial distribution. If you have not been taught it, see https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/binomial-distribution.html or https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/binomial-theorem/binomial-distribution-formula/

Comment: Second term of numerator should be 10 choose 5 rather than 5 choose 5. (Though it does look like you made the actual calculation with 10 choose 5.)

Comment: @paw88789: Thanks, seem particularly jinxed today !  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another very simple solution that might help you understand:

There are three possible outcomes where the difference between the # of odd and even rolls is <= 2:

- 5 odds & 5 evens,
- 6 odds & 4 evens,
- 4 odds & 6 evens

For simplicity we can look at just the number of evens. Let E be the binomial random variable representing the number of even #s we have rolled.

Therefore, the total probability of  the difference between the # of odd and even rolls being at most 3 is the sum of the probabilities of these 3 events:

```
P(E=5) = (10 choose 5) * 0.5^5 * 0.5^5
P(E=4) = (10 choose 4) * 0.5^4 * 0.5^6
P(E=6) = (10 choose 6) * 0.5^6 * 0.5^4   

P(E=5) + P(E=4) + P(E=6) = 0.656
```